# CSS Animation takes focus on Samsung s8

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I'm working on a site where I have a big infinite animation when the user enters the page. Now, on my computer(google chrome) and my phone(safari),
the animation looks fine and behaves correctly. However, when I tried to enter the site from my friend's Samsung Galaxy S8, the website start glitching.

The url for the site is: [website](http://philanthropistworld.com)

When I scroll the page down on Samsung Galaxy, the animation on the top always takes the focus, so it's impossible to scroll down to the rest of the page.

Here is my styles for the animation:

```
.static {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: -100px;
    opacity: 0.05;
    z-index: 230;
    user-select: none;
    user-drag: none;
}

.error {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 95px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 30px;
    animation: noise 2s linear infinite;
    overflow: default;
}

.error::after {
    content: 'Philanthropist';
    font-size: 95px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    color: blue;
    animation: noise-1 .2s linear infinite;
}

.error::before {
    content: 'Philanthropist';
    font-size: 95px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    color: red;
    animation: noise-2 .2s linear infinite;
}

.info {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    animation: noise-3 1s linear infinite;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .error,
    .error:after,
    .error:before {
        font-size: 50px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    .info {
        top: 140px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .error,
    .error::after,
    .error::before {
        font-size: 40px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
    .error,
    .error::after,
    .error::before {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .error {
        top: -60px;        
    }

    .info {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #logo-section {
        .arrow {
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes noise-1 {
    0%,
    20%,
    40%,
    60%,
    70%,
    90% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
        opacity: .1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: .5;
        left: -6px;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: .3;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: .6;
        left: 2px;
    }
}

@keyframes noise-2 {
    0%,
    20%,
    40%,
    60%,
    70%,
    90% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
        opacity: .1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: .5;
        left: 6px;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: .3;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: .6;
        left: -2px;
    }
}

@keyframes noise {
    0%,
    3%,
    5%,
    42%,
    44%,
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    4.3% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleY(1.7);
    }
    43% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(1.5);
    }
}

@keyframes noise-3 {
    0%,
    3%,
    5%,
    42%,
    44%,
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    4.3% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleY(4);
    }
    43% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(10) rotate(60deg);
    }
}
```

And here is the markup for the page:

```
<% include partials/header %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/aos.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/landing.css">

    <section id="logo-section">
        <div class="dark-overlay">
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="row h-100">
                    <div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center">
                        <div class="error">Philanthropist</div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <span class="info">The Bedroom</span>
                        <a href="#music-section" class="arrow"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="divider">
    </section>
    <!-- Music Section -->
    <section id="music-section" class="py-5">
        <div class="dark-overlay">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2 class="display-4 text-center" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="500" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="900">Music</h2>
                        <iframe data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="500" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1100" scrolling="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/30328335&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=true&amp;visual=false"
                         width="70%" data-embed="true" frameborder="no" height="450"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Newsletter -->
    <section id="newsletter-section" class="text-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column mb-5 mx-auto">
                    <form action="/subscribe" method="POST">
                        <h3 class="mb-4 text-center mx-auto">Stay Tuned</h3>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block">
                            Subscribe
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
                    <h3 class="mb-4 text-center mx-auto">Follow</h3>
                    <div id="social-media" class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mb-0">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/philanxy" class="mx-2 icon-button twitter" data-aos-delay="200" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800"
                         data-aos-once="true" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter icon-twitter"></i>
                            <span></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/philanxyxy/" class="mx-2 icon-button facebook" data-aos-delay="200" data-aos="fade-down"
                         data-aos-duration="800" data-aos-once="true" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook icon-facebook"></i>
                            <span></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/philanxy" class="mx-2 icon-button soundcloud" data-aos-delay="200" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800"
                         data-aos-once="true" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa fa-soundcloud icon-soundcloud"></i>
                            <span></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://philanthropist.bandcamp.com/" class="mx-2 icon-button bandcamp" data-aos-delay="200"
                         data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="800" data-aos-once="true" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa fa-bandcamp icon-bandcamp"></i>
                            <span></span>
                        </a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <% include partials/footer %>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/aos.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/landing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/navbar-fixed.js"></script>
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: As I don't have a Galaxy S8 to debug this, my best guess is that it might be related to the `opacity: 0`. Try wether this is still a problem with `opacity: 0.004`, or basically anything but 0.